# Android SocketException 'Socket is closed' closed even after socket.isClosed() is used

Tags: java, android, sockets, socketexception

I have an app in which I use a socket to listen for messages from a server, it has two activities each with their own method to handle the messages.

When I start the second from the first, I close the socket listener for that activity and start a new one in the second activities `onCreate` method. However, when I switch activities, I get a `java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed` error.

```
public synchronized void run(){
    //Check if the thread has been shut down
    while(!this.stopped){
        socket = null;
        try{
            //Socket
            socket = new DatagramSocket(port);
            //Packet
            byte[] data = new byte [1024];
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
            if(!socket.isClosed()){
                //Store data from socket into packet
                socket.receive(packet);
                //Create a string from the data
                String received = new String(packet.getData(),packet.getOffset(),packet.getLength());

                //Log the string TODO remove this
                Log.i("RECEIVED", received);

                //Get a new message object from the handler
                Message msg = commandHandler.obtainMessage();
                //Store the string in the message
                msg.obj = received;
                //Send the message to the handler
                commandHandler.sendMessage(msg);
            }

        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            if(socket != null)
                socket.close();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Close the listener
 */
public void shutDown(){
    this.stopped = true;
    if(socket != null){
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

As you can see from above, I use `!socket.isClosed()` to check if the socket is closed before receiving the message

The error trace:

```
06-27 19:48:12.129: W/System.err(19460): java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
06-27 19:48:12.129: W/System.err(19460):    at libcore.io.Posix.recvfromBytes(Native Method)
06-27 19:48:12.129: W/System.err(19460):    at libcore.io.Posix.recvfrom(Posix.java:136)
06-27 19:48:12.129: W/System.err(19460):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:164)
06-27 19:48:12.129: W/System.err(19460):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:513)
06-27 19:48:12.129: W/System.err(19460):    at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.doRecv(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:161)
06-27 19:48:12.129: W/System.err(19460):    at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:169)
06-27 19:48:12.129: W/System.err(19460):    at java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(DatagramSocket.java:253)
06-27 19:48:12.129: W/System.err(19460):    at com.android.homeservice.server.TabletListener.run(TabletListener.java:54)
```

**UPDATE**

So it turns out I have been calling the `start()` method of the thread twice in my second activity, once in `onCreate` and again in `onStart` which had been left over from a previous version of the code. Thank you for all your answers anyway, and sorry if I have wasted your time

Comment: The socket can actually be closed after checking if its closed, for example while waiting to receive data.  When and where are you calling socket.close()?

Comment: I call the shutDown() method before I create the intent to start the new activity to try and close the previous ones listener

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest a rearchitecture.  Keep the socket handling all on the thread, and just tell the thread when it should exit.  When the thread exits, close the socket.

```
public synchronized void run(){
    //Check if the thread has been shut down
    Socket socket = new DatagramSocket(port);
    while(!this.stopped){
        socket = null;
        try{
            //Socket
            //Packet
            byte[] data = new byte [1024];
                //Store data from socket into packet
                socket.receive(packet);
                //Create a string from the data
                String received = new String(packet.getData(),packet.getOffset(),packet.getLength());

                //Log the string TODO remove this
                Log.i("RECEIVED", received);

                //Get a new message object from the handler
                Message msg = commandHandler.obtainMessage();
                //Store the string in the message
                msg.obj = received;
                //Send the message to the handler
                commandHandler.sendMessage(msg);
            }

        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            if(socket != null)
                socket.close();
        }
    }
    socket.close()
}

/**
 * Close the listener
 */
public void shutDown(){
    this.stopped = true;

}
```

Comment: `DatagramSocket.receive()` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly someone else closed it between the isClosed() test and the line that threw the exception.

Make 'socket' a local variable, then no-one else can close it.

But creating a socket every time around the loop ins completely pointless in the first place. Just use the same socket for the life of the thread. If you never close it inside the loop it can't possibly throw that exception, and you never need to test for it.